# hasMoreElements() en StringTokenizer solo devuelve true

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buenas.
Tengo el siguiente código en java, estoy desarrollando una aplicación para Android. El código es:

```
    bajaRepostajeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String repostajeString = bajaRepostajeSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(repostajeString, "\t");
            int k = 0;
            while (st.hasMoreElements()){
                switch (k){
                    case 0:
                        establecimiento.setNombreEstablecimiento(token.nextToken());
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        repostaje.setPrecioTotal(Double.parseDouble(token.nextToken()));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        vehiculo.setMarca(token.nextToken());
                        break;
                }
                k++;
            }
```

El caso es que una vez que entra en el bucle while nunca sale de él, probé también con `hasMoreTokens()` y el resultado sigue siendo el mismo. ¿Alguien podría decirme el error que estoy cometiendo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Una vez que tienes mas elementos tienes que quitarlos para que deje de tenerlos y pare el `while`?

Comment: ¿Como podría hacer eso? Según la documentación de java no hay método para hacer tal cosa.

Comment: No necesitas método; es tu algoritmo el que decide que no quiere hacer más de 3 iteraciones. Lo que sugiere @lois6b es que, aparte del `hasMoreTokens()`, compruebes en el `while` si `k` es menor que 3...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una vez dentro del bucle tienes que llamar a `nextElement()` o `nextToken()` para que pase al siguiente elemento. En tu caso si `k` es 3 o más, nunca pasaría al siguiente elemento, y por lo tanto solo pasaría 3 veces al siguiente elemento (en los casos de `0`, `1` y `2`).

```
while (st.hasMoreElements()){
    switch (k){
        case 0:
            establecimiento.setNombreEstablecimiento(token.nextToken());
            break;
        case 1:
            repostaje.setPrecioTotal(Double.parseDouble(token.nextToken()));
            break;
        case 2:
            vehiculo.setMarca(token.nextToken());
            break;
        default:
            st.nextElement();
    }
    k++;
}
```

Comment: Error de noob, muchas gracias.

Comment: Otro error que veo es que en el while utilizas st (st.hasMoreElements()) mientras que en el switch utilizas en algunos casos token (token.nextToken()). Son variables distintas.

Adicionalmente aclararía que nextElement() y nextToken() son lo mismo solo que nextElement devuelve un Object y nextToken devuelve un String, aunque ambos 'consumen' el elemento de la colección.

Answer (score 1):

El problema parece más bien causado por un k que no es 0, 1, ó 2. En ese caso no se haría nextToken, no se avanzaría, y siempre habría más elementos, ya que no se avanza nunca al siguiente.

Nota: nextElement es lo mismo pero devolviendo Object, es el método de la interfaz padre de StringTokenizer, y por tanto también consume un elemento. La respuesta de @cnbandicoot es errónea por tanto.

Comment: Cierto. He cambiado la frase para aclarar este detalle. Gracias.